# How to make the country code come inside the form field in flutter using intl_phone_number_input

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, dart-packages

[image]

I want to make the country code pick come inside the `textformfield()` like a prefix icon. How do I do that?. This is the code I used from [intl_phone_number_input](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_number_input).

```
InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
          onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
            print(number.phoneNumber);
          },
          onInputValidated: (bool value) {
            print(value);
          },
          selectorConfig: SelectorConfig(
            selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
          ),
          ignoreBlank: false,
          autoValidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
          selectorTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          initialValue: number,
          textFieldController: controller,
          formatInput: false,
          keyboardType:
              TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true),
          inputBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
          onSaved: (PhoneNumber number) {
            print('On Saved: $number');
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 12):

You would need to set **setSelectorButtonAsPrefixIcon** inside **InternationalPhoneNumberInput** to true.

```
selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
                        selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType.BOTTOM_SHEET,
                        setSelectorButtonAsPrefixIcon: true,
                        leadingPadding: 20,
                        useEmoji: true,
                      ),
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer